# MySQL update where clause is being ignored

Tags: mysql

Here is my stored procedure:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `User_Confirm`(id INT)
BEGIN
  UPDATE 
    `User` 
  SET
    ConfirmedAt = UTC_TIMESTAMP() 
  WHERE `Id` = id ;
END$$
```

If I run

```
`CALL `User_Confirm`(19);`
```

I get this message saying the whole table has been updated:

```
1 queries executed, 1 success, 0 errors, 0 warnings

Query: call `User_Confirm`(19)

11 row(s) affected

Execution Time : 0.040 sec
Transfer Time  : 0.145 sec
Total Time     : 0.186 sec
```

User 19 does exist, why is this happening

---

### UPDATE

If I run this extraction from the stored procedure only one row gets updated as expect, so it definitely has something to do with the stored procedure:

```
 UPDATE 
    `User` 
  SET
    ConfirmedAt = UTC_TIMESTAMP() 
  WHERE `Id` = 19 ;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

probably self referencing on id, try:

```
.... WHERE `USER`.`Id` = id ;
```

Comment: Does this actually work?  I would think the second `id` would still be interpreted as `user.id`.

Answer (score 4):

Your problem is that the parameter name to the stored procedure is the same as the column name.  It is a good idea to prefix parameter names with something obvious.  Try this:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `User_Confirm`(param_id INT)
BEGIN
  UPDATE `User` 
      SET ConfirmedAt = UTC_TIMESTAMP() 
      WHERE `Id` = param_id ;
END$$
```

Comment: I am going to take your advice and prefix all params with 'p'

Comment: This helped me! I recommend putting a `_` in front of the name

Comment: @KevinDanikowski . . . Ironically, I usually use `in_` for in parameters.  I think I wanted to emphasize that distinction between parameters and columns so I used `param_` here.

Answer (score 1):

MySQL is somethings* not case sensitive, would that be the reason?

Comment: "MySQL is not case sensitive" --- it's a bit unclear

Comment: It is case sensitive for table names on linux, case insensitive for columns, but that is not the issue here.

Comment: I take that back (about being the issue here) as @Axel points out! It most definitely is the issue, is comparing the parameter to the parameter which always is true, hence the full table update.

Answer (score 1):

I think MySQL is ignoring your input argument, because the name matches the name of a column in one of the tables referenced in the UPDATE statement.

Let me rephrase that...

you think your predicate is of the form:

```
WHERE col = input_argument
```

But MySQL is actually seeing your predicate as:

```
WHERE col = col
```

or, as

```
WHERE input_argument = input_argument
```

The latter will be true for EVERY row in the table, the former will be true for every row that has a a non-null value stored in col.  (A simple test will reveal whether it's the column reference takes precedence, or a variable reference takes precedence. I do know that in Oracle, DML statements in PL/SQL blocks, column references take precedence over PL/SQL variables, and there is NO warning.)

A quick test would be rename the input argument, so that it doesn't match any column name.

Another workaround may be to use a MySQL user variable, (be careful of implicit datatype conversions), e.g.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `User_Confirm`(parameterId INT)
BEGIN
  SET @argId := parameterId;
  UPDATE `User` 
     SET ConfirmedAt = UTC_TIMESTAMP()
   WHERE `Id` = @argId ;
END$$
```

Comment: I may have 99 problems, but user variables are not going to be one of them :)